# Data not being passed from View into ViewModel in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, firebase-authentication

I'm new to iOS development. I am learning about MVVM. I am trying to hook up my app to firebase for authentication. It seems like everything is working because it's all building. BUT I force unwrapped the localized description error after I checked to see if it's not nil, and I do infact have an error message of "Password must be 6 characters or more." and the test password I'm setting up is more than 6 characters, so I think the problem is that the information is not being captured from the MainView to the Viewmodel...?

Please look at my code and let me know.

I currently have 3 files:
SplashScreenView

```
import SwiftUI

struct SplashScreenView: View {
    @State private var isActive = false
    @State private var size = 0.7
    @State private var opacity = 0.5
    
    var body: some View {
        
        if isActive {
            withAnimation{
                MainView().environmentObject(AuthViewModel())
            }
        } else {
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30, style: .continuous)
                    .foregroundStyle(LinearGradient(colors: [.orange, .red], startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
                
                
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                VStack {
                    VStack{
                        Image("logo")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 250)
                    }
                    .scaleEffect(size)
                    .opacity(opacity)
                    .onAppear(){
                        withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 1.2)) {
                            self.size = 0.9
                            self.opacity = 1.0
                        }
                    }
                }.onAppear() {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.5) {
                        self.isActive = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SplashView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SplashScreenView()
    }
}
```

MainView:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct MainView: View {
    
    @State var email = ""
    @State var password = ""
    @EnvironmentObject var authModel:AuthViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.theme.blue
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30, style: .continuous)
                .foregroundStyle(LinearGradient(colors: [.orange, .red], startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
                .frame(width: 1000, height: 450)
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(15))
                .offset(x: 20)
            
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                
                Image("logo")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(width: 100)
                    .offset(y: 10)
                
                Text("Welcome")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(Font.custom("Poppins-Bold", size: 40))
                    .offset(y:-10)
                
                // Email TextField
                TextField("", text: $email)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .textFieldStyle(.plain)
                    .placeholder(when: email.isEmpty) {
                        Text("Email Address")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(Font.custom("Poppins-Light", size: 20))
                    }
                
                // Email TextBox
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width:350, height: 1)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(.top, -5)
                
                // Password TextField
                SecureField("", text: $password)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .textFieldStyle(.plain)
                    .placeholder(when: password.isEmpty) {
                        Text("Password")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(Font.custom("Poppins-Light", size: 20))
                    }
                
                // Password TextBox
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width:350, height: 1)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(.top, -5)
                
                Button {
                    authModel.register()
                } label: {
                    Text("Sign Up")
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 40)
                        .background(
                            .orange
//                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous)
//                                .fill(.linearGradient(colors: [.red, .orange], startPoint: .topTrailing, endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
                            )
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .font(Font.custom("Poppins-Medium", size: 18))
                }
                
                Spacer()
                Spacer()
                // Login Link
                HStack {
                    Text("Already Have An Account?")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(Font.custom("Poppins-Medium", size: 18))
                    Button {
                        authModel.login()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Login")
                            .foregroundColor(.orange)
                            .font(Font.custom("Poppins-Medium", size: 18))
                    }
                }.offset(y: 100)
                
                
                    
            }
            .frame(width: 350, height: 60)
        }.ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

struct MainView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MainView().environmentObject(AuthViewModel())
    }
}

extension View {
    func placeholder<Content: View>(
        when shouldShow: Bool,
        alignment: Alignment = .leading,
        @ViewBuilder placeholder: () -> Content) -> some View {

        ZStack(alignment: alignment) {
            placeholder().opacity(shouldShow ? 1 : 0)
            self
        }
    }
}
```

and AuthViewModel:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase


class AuthViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    
    func register() {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: MainView().email, password: MainView().password) { result, error in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func login() {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: MainView().email, password: MainView().password) { result, error in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    
}
```

and for 'auth view model' before, I had had a `@published var mainView = MainView()` but I don't think that's right...if someone can please explain what I'm doing wrong, I'd REALLY appreciate it!!! I did search on here, but the other similar questions to mine was in C# or another language.

Comment: Swift and SwiftUI is designed around value types so MVVM doesn't make sense and the View struct and property wrapeprs already fill the role of the UIView's model so you just need to put the effort in and learn SwiftUI's features. The folks that filled the Internet with MVVM articles now admitting they were wrong, e.g. https://azamsharp.com/2022/07/17/2022-swiftui-and-mvvm.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call `MainView()` you are creating a different instance, of the view, one does not know about the other.

```
class AuthViewModel: ObservableObject {
    func register(email: String, password: String)  {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { result, error in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func login(email: String, password: String) {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { result, error in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then use

```
authModel.register(email: email, password: password)

authModel.login(email: email, password: password)
```

Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui), if you don't focus on the basics you will face an uphill battle.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, I am reading and doing them, but I learn best by doing. Trying and failing and learning. Your answer helped a ton. thanks!